# Push Notifications are not working on production (adhoc) profile iOS QuickBlox

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, quickblox, xcode7.1

I am using Quick Blox for Push notification. Push notification is working when installed through Xcode (developer profile). But when I archive and export (adhoc build) app using adhoc profile it won't work.

I double check the app identifier is enabled for push notification and both certificates (developer and production) are created and uploaded on quickblox portal (push notification/settings).

To check apple portal(app identifier and certificates) and quickblox settings are done correctly, I did the following:

1. I downloaded push notification sample app provided by quickblox
2. I change the identifier with my app identifier.
3. I set my certificates in build settings (developer and adhoc)
4. I change keys in code with my quickblox app (which I used in my app)
5. I run through xcode and archive (adhoc build) both works like a charm

But when I try with my own app It does not work. I have no clue how to trouble shoot it as I don't get any exception or error in log.

Any body has any idea how to deal with it?

Xcode Version: 7.1 (7B91B)
iOS: 9.1 and 9.2

Comment: Which iOS SDK do you use?

Comment: I am using IOS SDK 7

Comment: I mean QuickBlox iOS SDK, which version?